# Set files.txt into program's arguments in code blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

My question is simple, I am a beginner in c language, I am currently developing the hangman game on code blocks. To do this a restriction was imposed on me, the file in which my word dictionary is located, I must pass it as an argument in my program. I saw in my research that in the project -> Set program's arguments .. tab, we can add arguments, but I cannot pass my text file as a parameter. Anyone have a solution please? thank you so much

I pass it like this :

[image]

But when I build my program it does not detect my file.

this is the code that tries to read the file

```
char *read_file(int ac, char **av, int *lifes, char **word)
{
 int fd = -1;
 int nb_caractere = 0;
 char *buffer = calloc(1,sizeof(char));

 if((fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
 {
   printf("Aucun fichier ou dossier. \n");
   return (NULL);
 }
 lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
 while(read(fd, buffer, 1) > 0)
 {
   nb_caractere++;
 }
 lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
 buffer = calloc(nb_caractere+1, sizeof(char));
 memset(buffer, 0, nb_caractere+1);
 read(fd, buffer, nb_caractere);
 close(fd);
 return (buffer);
}
```

and the main how call this funtion is this :

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  int lifes = 10;
  char *word = NULL;
  char *hide_word = NULL;

  srand(time(NULL));
  if(ac < 2 || ac > 3)
  {
    printf("Nombres d'arguments incorrect !\n");
    return (84);
  }
  if(ac == 3)
  { 
    lifes = atoi(av[2]);
  }
  if(init_game(lifes, &word, &hide_word, read_file(ac, av, &lifes, 
  &word)) == 84 )
  {
    free(word);
    return (84);
  }
  game_loop(lifes, word, hide_word);
  free(word);
  free(hide_word);
  return 0;
}
```

the output of this code is "aucun fichier ou dossier"

Comment: Maybe the file is in a different directory from where the executable is being run? Try using an absolute path to the file instead of the relative path you used.

Comment: no it's still the same problem, no file found

Comment: Can you post the code that's trying to find the file, and the program arguments you used?

Comment: Also, we need a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, you don't show how the function is called so we can't verify whether the correct parameters are passed in. Finally please clarify what "cannot pass my text file" means exactly. That is, what actual error is your program getting?

Comment: i push the code in my question

Comment: Your question claims the issue is with passing in the parameter but that is not necessarily the correct conclusion. Have you examined/printed out what the `av[1]` value is? It could be the `open` is failing for some other reason and not because the parameter has not been passed in correctly. Print `av[1]` and also call `perror` to get a more specific error for the `open` call.